# What's the most efficient way to identify a “default” position on a board that can be flipped and rotated?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am currently implementing an AI playing a simple board game (5 in a row) in Python 3.6. The board is 7x7 and each field can contain either a black or a white stone.

To simplify the problem, I want to treat rotated or flipped board positions the same way. Before I feed the board state to my algorithm, I want to rotate it to a "default" position, lacking a better word for it. The AI must only learn a strategy for this position and can ignore the other 7 possible equivalents.

Each board exists in 8 different equal positions (4 rotations + 4 rotations flipped). The board state is stored as a 2D matrix (0=empty, 1=black, 2=white) as a numpy array.

What is the most efficient way to find my "default" view? A simple approach would be calculating all representations, flattening the 2D 7x7 matrix to a 1D 49 matrix, treating it as a long number and call the highest or lowest number my default.

This feels cumbersome and inefficient. Is there a better pattern to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NumPy the most efficient is usually what you can vectorize.  I'd first compute the indices that represent the transformations:

```
xform = [np.arange(7*7).reshape(7,7)]
xform.extend(np.rot90(xform[0], k) for k in range(1, 4))
xform.extend(list(map(np.fliplr, xform)))
xform = np.asarray(xform)
```

Now when you have a board:

```
board = np.random.randint(0, 3, (7, 7))
```

You can generate all the representations in one efficient operation:

```
board.ravel()[xform]
```

You might rather use `xform.reshape(8, 7*7)` first to get flat representations.  From there you can lexicographically sort the 8 arrays:

```
order = np.lexsort(board.ravel()[xform.reshape(8, 7*7)].T)
canon = board.ravel()[xform[order[0]]]
```

Now, surely this is not the computer science optimal way, but it might be pretty close to optimal with NumPy, because the operations needed are simple and few.

Comment: Thanks for providing this interesting approach! Unfortunately you lost me at "board.ravel()[xform]". What is this line supposed to do? I tried it in the interactive python CLI and I get an error (IndexError: too many indices for array).

Comment: @Demento: Sorry I left out one step (`xform = np.asarray(xform)`).  Fixed now, please try.